# Using \newcommand and \input

Tags: input

I like to use variables for my paths, so that if I migrate to another system/username, I don't have to change every path name. This does not seem to be working with the `input` command. I have the following in my `main.tex` file:

```
\newcommand{\rootFolder}{/home/user/Documents/tex}
....
\input{\rootFolder/foo/bar.tex}
```

But I get the following error.

```
1 || ** \rootFolder/foo/bar.tex:     
2 main.tex|86 error| Could not open "\rootFolder/foo/bar.tex"
```

My spider senses tell me it is not expanding `\rootFolder`. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT** User Peter Grill asked me for a minimal working example (MWE) so here it is. Also, I should have mentioned that I am getting this error from inside Vim.

**test.tex**:

```
hello world
```

**main.tex (local path)**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\input{test.tex}
\end{document}

% Works Fine
```

**main.tex (variable)**:

```
\newcommand{\rootFolder}{/home/user/Documents}

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\input{\rootFolder/test.tex}
\end{document}

% Vim Error:
% 1 || ** \rootFolder/test.tex:                                                                                                                                      
% 2 main.tex|5 error| Could not open "\rootFolder/test.tex"
```

**main.tex (edef)**:

```
\newcommand{\rootFolder}{/home/user/Documents}

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\edef\ExpandedFileName{\rootFolder/test.tex}\input{\ExpandedFileName}
\end{document}

% Vim Error:
% 1 || ** \ExpandedFileName:                                                                                                                                      
% 2 main.tex|5 error| Could not open "\ExpandedFileName"
```

**main.tex (no edef)**:

```
\newcommand{\rootFolder}{/home/user/Documents}

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ExpandedFileName{\rootFolder/test.tex}\input{\ExpandedFileName}
\end{document}

% Vim Error:
% 1 || ** \ExpandedFileName:                                                                                                                                      
% 2 main.tex|5 error| Could not open "\ExpandedFileName"
% pdflatex Error:
% Undefined control sequence.
% l.5     \ExpandedFileName{\rootFolder/test.tex}\input{\ExpandedFileN...
```

**main.tex (expandafter)**:

```
\newcommand{\rootFolder}{/home/user/Documents}

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\expandafter\input\expandafter{\rootFolder/test.tex}
\end{document}

% Vim Error:
% 1 test.tex|5 error| Don't use "\expandafter" in LaTeX documents
```

Comment: The usual way of trying to fix that is `\edef\ExpandedFileName{\rootFolder/foo.tex}
\input{\ExpandedFileName}`, but this does not appear to be the case as the error message I get is `LaTeX Error: File /home/user/Documents/tex/foo.tex not found` -- identical message if I use the `\edef` or not.

Comment: There probably is something else going on, so perhaps you should compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that reproduces this error message including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages.

Comment: @Peter: without `\expandafter\input\expandafter{\ExpandedFileName}`, you'd run into the same issue as before anyway, wouldn't you?

Comment: @PeterGrill just added the MWEs

Comment: Using a command in this way should principally work. If the file is nevertheless not found then either the path is wrong or the security settings in your texmf.cnf (openin_any) doesn't allow absolute pathes.

Comment: Addition: as I have some doubts that the real file name is "foo/bar": Avoid non-ascii chars, spaces and additional dots in file names. Normally it is also better to use simply `\input{file}` instead of `\input{file.tex}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the output you show this is not a Tex error (and presumably LaTeX handles your code correctly) it is an error from Vim, by which I assume you are using the editor that isn't emacs:-) It looks like you are using a Vim mode that thinks it understands TeX syntax and is trying to do something useful, but actually it doesn't understand the full command usage.